# Matrix multiplying method gives out additional column filled with zeros

Tags: c++, matrix

I wrote a method that multiplies matrices. It works fine, but gives additional column of zeros. The result of multiplying is correct. Here is the code of method:

```
Matrix Matrix::multiplyMatrix(Matrix second)
{

        vector<vector<double> > sum(vec.size(), vector<double> (vec[0].size()));

    if (vec[0].size()!=second.vec.size())
    {
        throw "Dimensions are not correct";
    }
    else 
    {
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<second.vec[0].size(); j++)
        {
        sum[i][j]=0;
        for (int k=0; k<vec[0].size(); k++)
        {
            sum[i][j]+=vec[i][k]*second.vec[k][j];
        }
    }
    }

    Matrix out(vec.size(), vec[0].size());
    out.vec=sum;
    return out;
    }
}
```

From main:

```
Matrix A("A.txt",3,4);
Matrix B("B.txt",4,3);

auto C=A.multiplyMatrix(B);
C.write("C.txt");
```

Matrices:

```
A:

2 3 4 4
1 2 4 6
1 1 0 1
```

and

```
B:
1 2 3
5 6 7
9 1 5
4 5 5
```

Instead of 3x3 matrix it gives:

```
69 46 67 0  
71 48 67 0  
10 13 15 0
```

Do you know what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: In the very first line, where you define dimensions for `sum`, you don't look at `second`'s dimensions at all. You make the resulting matrix always the same size as the first operand.

Comment: oh, yeah, that's true... but how do I do that?

Comment: @frushan Does this code (which you wrote) give you a clue `for (int j=0; j<second.vec[0].size(); j++)`? That code tells you how big the second dimension of `sum` needs to be.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix named "out" has the wrong dimensions, also, int the first line of your code, the sum has wrong dimensions too.

the first line should change to:

```cpp
vector<vector<double> > sum(vec.size(), vector<double> (second.vec[0].size()));
```

the definition of out should change to:

```cpp
Matrix out(vec.size(), second.vec[0].size());
```